# what is an alternative version of sys.sdout.flush() except its on kivy ui texts?

Tags: python, kivy

the question is pretty simple but yeah couldnt find an answer, I've asked previously before too but yeah no responses and even views, so made my goal more clear this time
example, this doesnt work. it will wait until the full char adding to the text is done and THEN show the text

```
class buttonex(BoxLayout):
    mytext=StringProperty("helloyes")
    hello=ObjectProperty(None)
    def on_button_click(self):
        self.hello.text=""
        for char in "hi noob lol hahaha":
            sleep(0.07)
            self.hello.text=self.hello.text+char
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Better will be, if you edit the post to include the above comment, as [**comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) is not meant to be answering or suggesting correction.

Comment: alr, idk if I can post this but I'll post it anyway but I've corrected the edits and my bad @ApuCoder (I'll delete the previous comment and shortly after you reply, this comment aswell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the question,

> what is an alternative version of sys.sdout.flush() except its on kivy ui texts?

Here is a simple implementation using `Clock`.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import (NumericProperty, StringProperty)
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout



Builder.load_string("""

<TextBox>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "10dp"

    Label:
        id: label

    TextInput:
        multiline: 0
        hint_text: "Enter text and hit enter"
        on_text_validate: root.type_text(self.text)

""")



class TextBox(BoxLayout):

    cache_text = StringProperty("") # For storing the entered text.
    index = NumericProperty(0) # For iteration over cache_text.

    def type_text(self, txt, *args):
        self.cache_text = txt # Store the entered text here.
        # For more control you may use method Clock.create_trigger.
        self.ev = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_text, 0.25) # Update text after every 0.25 sec.

    def update_text(self, *args):
        if self.index < len(self.cache_text):
            val = self.cache_text[self.index]
            self.ids.label.text += val # Appending to existing text.
            self.index += 1
        else:
            self.ids.label.text = "" # Comment it out to retain the text.
            self.index = 0 # Reset index.
            self.cache_text = "" # Clear cache.
            self.ev.cancel() # Cancel text updation.



class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return TextBox()



TestApp().run()
```